# What config files are involved in master volume levels?

Tags: root-access, lineageos, volume, 7.1-nougat

I recently took the plunge and installed LineageOS on my Nexus 5X. My hope was that this would allow me to increase headphone volume as my favourite headphones are not loud enough with the stock volume controls.

After much googling and trying of apps pre-root, I concluded that I would need to delve deeper. I've now tried a couple of methods touted as solutions, namely editing build.prop and mixer_paths.xml but neither of these approaches has influenced volume levels.

I would like to know:

Is this technically possible by editing config files?
Why don't apps claiming to boost volume on the play store actually work?
What settings/files do those apps try and alter?

Although I am specifically looking for information for LineageOS 14.1 / Android 7.1, this information might be useful to a broader audience.

I have tried:

Manually editing mixer_paths.xml and adjusting Headphone volumes in `<path name="headphones">` and also editing earpiece and headset values in `build.prop`.

N.B I am not looking to increase the granularity of control over the volume but to boost the volume level beyond the loudest setting in stock Android

Comment: I don't think you have a universally fitting answer. I have modified volume on three devices , Note 2 on Kit Kat, Honor 6 on Kit kat and Moto X Play on Marshmallow. In all the cases, the files were in a different location. It depends on the ROM, is my conclusion

Comment: Thanks. Do you remember which files?

Comment: For [Moto X](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x-style/themes-apps/how-to-increase-headphone-volume-t3302198). Best is to search on XDA or if you are using custom kernel apps like kernel aduitor can help

Comment: Or search on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/28jnc2/simple_tweak_to_increase_speaker_and_headphone/)